# How to deal with difficult boss. Should I continue or move on?

Tags: management, australia

I joined this company as a developer in June 2016 so around two years I am working here. The work pressure is too much.So literally this is no work life balance.On top of that my boss is really a bad person. He didn't paid me for those extra hours i did while on student visa(FYI on student visa i cant work more than 20 hours. But i did sometimes but he paid me 20 hours. I didn't wanted to break the law so didn't asked pay for extra hours).

Little history though, I was new in the country(AU) and was on student visa. So that means I couldn't work full time. Most of the IT companies needs full time so it was really hard to get development job. I needed experience so I finally got hired here.

My boss is really a mean person: I have seen nearly 10-15 people leaving the company while I am working there because he is really a manipulative mean person. He hires people on probation and once he get the knowledge to do the reform in the system he just simply get rid of them.

Two months back my visa status changed; that means I can finally work full time. My boss said to me that he will be changing the payrate to a senior developer. As previously I got some experience. But it's been over two months I didn't got my pay raise. I already asked him twice but he said he will do pretty soon.

Second most important issue is because of his behaviour it gives me anxiety. I am writing this on Sunday night. Just by thinking of getting up in morning for him makes me scared I couldn't sleep.

I like the work which I do there it's pretty cool and used by thousands of people all over Australia. So what should I do? Should I move to another job 
 because now I can and have working rights or get a raise here?

Comment: Nothing in your post indicates that your boss is bi-polar. Bi-polar is someone who changes between different mood states, usually over the course of months.

Comment: I fail to see how all this is your companies/boss fault. You sound like someone who was more than willing to commit in crime, and now cries wolf because whow, acutally he got what he asked for. Did it ever occur to you to actually either follow the law or - get another job? After working with someone willing to lie (if not to you then to a lot of other places) constantly - why do you think you magically will not get the same treatment? Did you talk to a lawyer? Psyhchologist?

Comment: Please don't use the word 'bipolar' to mean 'I think he is bad'. Bipolar disorder is a real disease, and to use it indiscriminately like this gives real sufferers a bad name.

Comment: I edited your title to remove the reference to bipolar, per the other commenters. You may want to further edit your post to clarify what your goals are and explain the specific question you're asking for help with. As it is right now, your question(s) are very open ended, opinion based, and hard to answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't trust your employer, if promises were broken and money wasn't paid, then your possible choices are changing the behaviour of the employer (chances are about zero), or looking for a different employer.

Find a new position, sign the contract, give notice to your current employer, don't look back.

Comment: Unless the OPs visa is tied to this employer.